# How to calculate paypal fees, 2.9% +0.30 doesn't work for some cases variable FEEAMT in checkout method doesn't match

Tags: paypal, checkout

thanks for reading this.

I am implementing paypal checkout in my website it is working but i want to make a simple fees calculator for paypal in order to help the user, i went to paypal and they said their fees amount is 2.9% +0.30 fixed, but it is not working for some cases, for example: deposit $1.34

2.9 % = $0.04 rounded + $0.30 = $0.34, so i should get $1 credited but paypal send in its response in the field FEEAMT which indicate the "PayPal fee amount charged for the transaction" 0.35,

what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at online calculators for PayPal fees, they all come out with what you did.  Maybe PayPal has a Superman 3 scheme going on?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Maybe paypal add Cross border fee of 1.0%.

Some pages that make that calculations and can help you see what's going on.

PayPal Fee calculator: http://thefeecalculator.com/

PayPal ref: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-fees-outside

Comment: well, i am not sure if this 1.0% could be the trouble, i am using paypal sandbox at the moment, i am still in development, so i don't thing if paypal sandbox could detect different countries right now, i think all sub account are in the same country. First url calculate fees in same manner i mention $1.34, fees 0.34.

Comment: @Dev-cu ah... if you are on sandbox then as you say probably did not have cross border fee

Comment: thanks any way, you have been the only one who has reply, maybe people doesn't understand my question.

Comment: @deb-cu well, only 14 times this page have open, few people see it, and probably they do not have something to answer - its happens to me all the time :) Paypal fees is also for me an issue because I do not know them in advanced for sure, so if I charge too little I have problem to lose money. I need also to know the cost from the time I set the price, and I have see the same think happens to me, more charge on fee - and they call it cross border fee